# Mostrar los números primos de una lista creado por el usuario

Tags: python, lista

Estoy intentando crear una función que muestre los números primos de una lista de números que el usuario ha ingresado.
Mi problema es que mi código no realiza correctamente la parte en dónde se define cuáles son primos o si ningún número ingresado es primo. ¿Qué modificaciones podría hacer?

```
def numeros_primos():
    valores = []
    while True:
        try:
            valor = int(input("Ingrese los números: "))
            if valor == 0:
                break
            valores.append(valor)
        except ValueError:
            print("Inserta un número.")
    
    print(valores)           
            
    if valor > 1:
        cont = 0
        for i in range(2,valor):
            resto = valor % i
            
            if resto == 0:
                cont+=1
                
        if cont == 0:
            print("Los numeros primos son: ", valor)
   
        else:
            print("Ningún número ingresado es un número primo")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura de tu código puede mejorarse. Pero si no quieres cambiarlo mucho puedes usar una función para verificar si es o no primo.

Algo asi:

```
def isprime(num):
    if num> 1:  
        for n in range(2,num):  
            if (num % n) == 0:  
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

valores = []
while True:
    try:
        valor = int(input("Ingrese los números: "))
        if valor == 0:
            break
        valores.append(valor)
    except ValueError:
        print("Inserta un número.")

print(valores)           
        
primos=[]
for valor in valores:
    if isprime(valor):
        primos.append(valor)
if primos:
    print("Los numeros primos son: ", primos)

else:
    print("Ningún número ingresado es un número primo")
```

La función es al gusto de cada quien, este ejemplo es de [aqui.](https://www.pythonpool.com/check-if-number-is-prime-in-python/).

Answer (score 2):

Otra solución

```
def es_primo(n: int):
    if n % 2:
        for divisor in range(3, 1 + n // 2, 2):
            if n % divisor == 0:
                return False
    else:
        return False

    return True
```

Para mayor rapidez, chequea si es múltiplo de 2 y, en caso contrario, sólo chequea los divisores impares, hasta `~n/2`, ya que si no es primo, al menos un divisor tiene que ser menor a ese límite.

Para obtener los resultados pedidos un valor, comprobamos si es primo y, en tal caso, lo ponemos en la lista de salida `valores`:

```
valores = []
while True:
        try:
            valor = int(input("Ingrese los números: "))
            if valor == 0:
                break
            if es_primo(valor):
                valores.append(valor)
        except ValueError:
            print("Inserta un número válido.")
```

Al terminar, `valores` contendra todos los primos ingresados:

```
if valores:
   print("Los numeros primos son: ", valor)
else:
   print("Ningún número ingresado es un número primo")
```